# To find out whether a list is a sublist of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1=[1,3,8,10,23,8,8,10,23,3,8,10,23,3,8,10,23]
list2=[10,23,3]
cnt=list1.count(list2[0])
cnt1=1
j=0
while (cnt1<=cnt):
    list3=[]
    list3.append(list2[0])
    i=1
    k=list1.index(list2[0])
    while (i<len(list2)):
        list3.append(list1[k+i])
        i=i+1
    print (list3)    
    if (list2==list3):
        print ("list2 is a subset")
        j=j+1
    else:
        print ("list2 is not a subset")

    list1.remove(list2[0])    
    cnt1=cnt1+1    
print (list2,"occurs",j,"times")
```

I am getting this error.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python26\Lib\idlelib\sublist.py", line 12, in <module>
>     list3.append(list1[k+i])
> IndexError: list index out of range"
> ```

Comment: Not sure why you're complicating things this much. `from collections import Counter; print(not bool(Counter(list2) - Counter(list1)))`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, doesn't this lose any ordering?

Comment: Does it have to be a continuous sub_list, a slice?

Comment: @StephenRauch Point, it does. If that's a requirement, then that doesn't work, sadly. I was thinking more along the lines of "subset" accounting for duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

You're definitely over-complicating this - to the point where it is not obvious as to what your strategy actually is.

Here's a simple algorithm you could try and integrate:

1. Get the length of `list2`
2. Iterate through `list1`, accessing slices of the list of length `list2` (eg the first slice would be `[1, 3, 8]`, then the next would be `[3, 8, 10]`
3. Check if the slice is equal to `list2` - if it is then return True (or add 1 to the counter)
4. If you reach the end of the list - end

Answer (score 1):

You can test all the `list1` slices of the proper length for equality with `list2`. You can then use [**`sum`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to get the number of occurrences:

```
list1 = [1,3,8,10,23,8,8,10,23,3,8,10,23,3,8,10,23]
list2 = [10,23,3]

l1, l2 = len(list1), len(list2)
num_occurrences = sum(list1[i:i+l2] == list2 for i in range(l1 - l2 + 1))
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to do it:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

list1=[1,3,8,10,23,8,8,10,23,3,8,10,23,3,8,10,23]

list2=[10,23,3]

size = len(list2)

# convert to a queue
items = deque(list1)

count = 0

# iterate until no more sublists can be extracted
while len(items) >= size:
    current = list(islice(items, 0, size))

    # if the current sublist is equal to list1, increment count
    if current == list2:
        count += 1

    # pop the first element from this queue, ready for next sublist
    items.popleft()

print (list2,"occurs",count,"times")
```

Which Outputs:

```
[10, 23, 3] occurs 2 times
```

The approach of the above code:

- Convert `list1` to a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) object, which can pop objects off the front in `O(1)` time. This is `items` in the code.
- Store a `count` of identical lists found equal to `list2`.
- Check if the `current` sub list, the first `n` elements in `items` as a list, is equal to `list2`. Increment the count if it is equal.
- Pop the first item from `items` with `popleft()`, getting ready for the next sub list. So if my list is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, After processing `[1, 2, 3]`, pop `1` from `items`, and the next sub list to check is `[2, 3, 4]`.
- Keep doing this process until no `size` sub lists can be extracted. Then you can just print out the count at the end.